# Response.Cache + FileStreamResult = NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, filestreamresult

In my mvc 4 application i have a method which is streaming a file from a azure blob.

My code is pretty simple, all im doing is fetching the blob i wanna stream and then return it as FileStreamResult with.

```
return new FileStreamResult(blob.OpenRead(), contentType);
```

This code works fine. But I also want to set cache headers, so before I return the file im setting the headers like this :

```
Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 80000));
Response.Cache.SetSlidingExpiration(true);
```

Strangely modifying the Response.Cache doesn't work.

All im getting is an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have really tried to find the source of the exception but it always happens after `Application_EndRequest`.

I really can't understand why setting the `Response.Cache` would cause it all to break.

From the stacktrace :

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.] System.Web.HttpContext.RequestRequiresAuthorization() +30
>   System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule.OnLeave(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +9778761   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Exec‌​ute() +136
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

I guess that something that has to do with the "Response.Cache" object is disposed too early. Maybe I should try the set the cache-headers manually?

Comment: Set the debugger to break on all exceptions and post the stack trace of the exception. Enable "Show external code". Maybe you're disposing the "blob" before it is being read by ASP.NET?!

Comment: Updated with stacktrace.

Comment: And when you uncomment these 4 cache lines (just those!) the exception goes away?; Is `User.Identity` null when you check it in the debugger?